# Migrating from local to server - MySQL errors

Tags: migration

Hi this is my first time using WordPress and I'm having a nightmare trying to migrate a locally built site to a hosting server.

I exported my local database (MySQL 5.6.17) then tried to upload it to the database I created on the hosting providers site (MySQL 5.0.83) I keep getting the error `#1273 - Unknown collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. I looked around for ages and it appears to be because of the utf8mb4 upgrade in 5.5 I think (per [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/))

I've tried a suggestion I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190523/phpmysql-error-1273-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-general-ci) that says when exporting, change output compatibility from NONE to MYSQL40. When I do this then try import the database on the hosted server I keep getting the error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version`

I then looked at using the Duplicator plugin - I used it to create a package then uploaded the installer.php and archive files to the hosted server but now I don't know how to run the installer.php file. I've tried accessing the server using ftp but when I click the installer.php file it just opens as a text file.

Very frustrating. Hope someone can point me in the right direction. The SQL export and import would have been the easiest but I can't find a solution to export from a newer version to an older version that works cleanly.

Thanks for looking.

> **Edit 1**

I figured out how to run the Duplicator plugin installer.php (navigate to http://sitename.com/installer.php). I entered my database details then ran it but I'm getting multiple errors along the lines:

```
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
      `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL A...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_comments` (
      `comment_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL A...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_links` (
      `link_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_IN...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_options` (
      `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUT...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
      `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
      `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREME...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_term_relationships` (
      `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned N...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_term_taxonomy` (
      `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_terms` (
      `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_IN...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
    CREATE TABLE `wp_usermeta` (
      `umeta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUT...]
    **ERROR** database error write 'Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' - [sql=
```

There has to be an easier way of doing this

Comment: Use a cloud server for $10 a month and install any version of mysql you want seems easy enough. mysqldump and shove those bytes right into the db

Comment: Yes I'm going to contact the existing host and if they can't import the database for me I'll move host